# What anime are these figures from?

Tags: merchandise

These are figures I got off eBay; the seller didn't know the answer. Thank you so much!

[image]

[eBay Item - 3 Gashapon Figure Figurine Lot Sexy Girl Boy 3.75" Posable Anime Manga](https://www.ebay.com/itm/322097339447)

Comment: Guy on the left is pretty obviously [Duo Maxwell](http://gundam.wikia.com/wiki/Duo_Maxwell), from Gundam Wing.  Can't identify the other two, although I'm pretty certain they're not from Gundam Wing.